# CakePHP HTAccess 500 Internal Server Error, 404 Page Not Found errors

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I'm using `CakePHP 1.2` Version and When I upload my site on Live Server, it gives me `500 Internal Server Error`

When I check `mod_rewrite` in `phpinfo` function, its not visible, but on same server another Joomla site is running perfectly fine without any problem of htaccess or path rewrite issue with AceSEF Component of Joomla for htaccess page / paths, so I believe as this is `Shared server` it must be that way.

I have tried different options like adding 'RewriteBase /' in root .htaccess file or trying the same in app/webroot/.htaccess files as well but no solution works for me.

Even when I write, 'RewriteBase /' in root .htaccess and app/.htaccess file, error changes to `400 Page Not Found`. I don't know why.

Below is the .htaccess code:

root .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

app/.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

app/webroot/.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have read through some links like: [Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess](http://book.cakephp.org/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess) though not much helpful

Any answer or solution for this error? Much appreciated !!

Thanks

Comment: What is in the apache error logs?

Comment: @iamtheladylengend please verify database crendentials

Comment: @Leo: error log says 500 and 404 errors respectively

Comment: @MoyedAnsari: db credentials are also correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the rewrite module is linked in the enabled modules of apache. Like you said it isnt listed in phpinfo() so the module maybe isnt enabled and joomla has some workarounds.

(use following commands at your own risk, you need root access)
under debian/ubuntu; apache2 enable the module like that

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
ln -s ../mods-available/rewrite.load rewrite.load
```

you have to restart apache2

```
service apache2 restart
```

Then the module should be enabled! So try again.

Alternatively, tell the url you try to open!